# Stopping timeout started from an object instance when all references are lost

Tags: javascript, reference, settimeout

I made a polling system for which you must use instantiation, thus allowing you to have multiple pollers going at the same time.

The polling uses setTimeout to delay each request according to a defined poll rate.

Here is a very simplified version:

```
function Poller(url, rate, callback) {
  var timeoutReference = null;

  var public = {
    poll: function() {
      /* Request here i.e. $.GET(....)
         calling callback with recieved data on success */

      console.log("Poller running");

      timeoutReference = setTimeout(public.poll, rate);                
    },
    stop: function() { 
      clearTimeout(timeoutReference); 
    }
  }

  return public;    
}

var poller1 = new Poller('http://www.site.com/feed', 5000, readData);

poller1.poll();
```

Now if I do

```
poller1 = null;
```

The timeout is still running and will run forever. I need to do

```
poller1.stop(); 
poller1 = null;
```

for it to work as intended.

Is there any way to clear the timeout when all references are lost, thus omitting the need for calling poller1.stop(); before unreferencing the instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to "find" a lost timer index (they're just numbers).  You could always wrap "setTimeout()" in a function that keeps a global registry or something.  You'd still have the problem of having to identify them somehow, but there are several ways to approach that.

Comment: I suppose what I'm really looking for is for a old-skool destructor, something that gets called when all references are lost, but I know there is no such thing in JavaScript. Isn't it?

Comment: @McCoy no, there's nothing like that in JavaScript. I know of no way that an object can decide its fate, or even have anything happen at all, when it becomes fully dereferenced.

Comment: Thanks, seems there is no way to do what I want then. Will accept your answer :)